# Deferred ajax requests to IIS 7.5 hosted Web Api 2 app gives 500 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iis, asp.net-web-api2

The javascript code which calls the web api 2 app,

```
$.when(
      $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: "some/url",
         dataType: 'json',
         async: true
      }),
      $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: "some/url",
         dataType: 'json',
         crossDomain: true
      })
     ).then((data, data2) => {...
```

Error message: 500 (Internal Server Error)

If I nest the ajax requests in the previous requests success callback it starts to work again, which leads me to believe `IIS/Web Api 2` is not liking multiple concurrent requests?

Code that works,

```
     $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: "some/url",
         dataType: 'json',
         async: true,
         success: function () {
          $.ajax({
           type: 'get',
           url: "some/url",
           dataType: 'json',
           crossDomain: true,
           success: function() {...}
          })
        }
      })
```

Comment: Add the code that works to be sure what you mean. Add the full error message as text (not a image, it's not searchable). Edit your post. Basically a 500 means the server has problems. Depending on how well the server side is implemented a 500 might also indicate that request arguments are bad, check them.

Comment: "500" can mean any server error. Webservers are designed to handle multiple concurrent requests, so it's unlikely that *that's* the problem. IIS is usually pretty specific about what caused the problem, look at the error details in the network tab of the browser's developer tools.

Comment: The only error messages i get are "500:Internal server error" and "An error has occurred"